# Use pure JavaScript to close a div by clicking off after it's been opened with a click elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I am very aware of the JQuery-based responses to this question - please do not point me at those. I need a pure JavaScript solution to this.

Here's my particular quandary:

I create a button using a div which users can click to open a breadcrumbs view:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs_icon" class="dialog_button" data-tooltip="Breadcrumbs" onclick="showDiv()">
    <span class="breadcrumbs_icon" ></span>
</div>
```

Here's what I have so far to show the div:

```
function showDiv()
{   
    var breadcrumbsDiv = document.getElementById("breadcrumbs_flyout");
    if (breadcrumbsDiv.style.display=="none") {
        breadcrumbsDiv.style.display="block";
    }
    else {
        breadcrumbsDiv.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

So far so good.

I now need to be able to close that breadcrumbs view by clicking the button again (that's covered already) but also by clicking anywhere else in the document, except the breadcrumbs div itself.

And this is what I can't solve. Any document click event handler (no matter how primitive) I add closes the div before the browser has had time to render it.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout').onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target != document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout')) {
        document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

(Actually, the above example ONLY works if I click the div, which I can't explain.)

Any help and advice much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout').onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target != document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout')) {
        document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This is very close. You need to add an on-click handler to the `<body>`, and then filter out any events which have the flyout in their DOM hierarchy.

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    if(!isChildOfFlyout(e.target)) {
        document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout').style.display = 'none';

        // stop event propagation
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
        // clean up the handler (if appropriate)
        document.body.onClick = null;
    }
}

function isChildOfFlyout(node) {
  if (node === document.body) {
    return false;
  } else if (node === document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return isChildOfFlyout(node.parentNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew! Unfortunately this didn't work for me either. I get the same result as I did before: the div is hidden immediately because the click is registered as being out of the div which triggers the hiding, effectively before it's ever rendered in the browser.

Comment: Okay, I modified your if statement in the isChildOfFlyout function a little bit, adding:

} else if ((node === document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_icon')) && (document.getElementById('breadcrumbs_flyout').style.display == 'block')) {
  return true;

Which seems to be enough to capture the different conditions and display/hide the div when I need it. Thanks for getting me there dude!